# Saving objects to Mongodb with Promises

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, save

What's the correct way to use promises with Mongodb when saving objects to DB?

```
var saveObject = function(something1, something2,cb){ 
    var myObject = new Model();
    myObject.property1= 'something';
    myObject.property2= 'something2';
    myObject.save().then(cb(result));
}
```

this is not working for me, I'm using mongodb 2.6. 
thanks for your help

Comment: Readying more it seems that with the callback for save( function( err, object ,numberAfected){}) I would be fine regarding making async calls....

Comment: Since you're using mongoose, you'd want to check out their [docs on promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).